# How to find max value from struct?

Tags: c#

```
public struct nariai
{
    public string vardas;
    public string pavarde;
    public double eurai;
    public double centai;
    public double suma;
};
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double islaidos;
    double surinktiPinigai = 0;
    StreamReader failas = new StreamReader("nariai.txt");
    string a = failas.ReadLine();
    int nariuKiekis = int.Parse(a);
    nariai[] narys = new nariai[nariuKiekis];
    string[] info = new string[nariuKiekis];
    for (int i = 0; i < nariuKiekis; i++)
    {
        info[i] = failas.ReadLine();
        string[] informacija = info[i].Split(' ');
        narys[i].vardas = informacija[0];
        narys[i].pavarde = informacija[1];
        narys[i].eurai = double.Parse(informacija[2]);
        narys[i].centai = double.Parse(informacija[3]);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", narys[i].vardas, narys[i].pavarde, narys[i].eurai, narys[i].centai);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nariuKiekis; i++)
    {
        islaidos = narys[i].eurai * 100 + narys[i].centai;
        narys[i].suma = islaidos / 100 * 0.25;
        islaidos = narys[i].suma;
        Console.WriteLine(narys[i].suma);
        surinktiPinigai = surinktiPinigai + islaidos;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Surinkti pinigai bendroms išlaidoms: {0} Eurai.", surinktiPinigai);
}
```

File looks like that:

[image: file]

Command looks like that:

[image: command]

I need to find who has the biggest value in the structure "public double suma" and i need to write first name and last name of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq):

```
var maxNarys = narys.OrderByDescending(n => n.suma)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

And then access it's properties like this:

```
var maxNarvardas = maxNarys.vardas;
```

EDIT

Also looking at your code more closely:

it seems that you can concat your two loops and add a variables to find max:

```
var maxSuma = double.MinValue;
var maxIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < nariuKiekis; i++)
{
    info[i] = failas.ReadLine();
    string[] informacija = info[i].Split(' ');
    narys[i].vardas = informacija[0];
    narys[i].pavarde = informacija[1];
    narys[i].eurai = double.Parse(informacija[2]);
    narys[i].centai = double.Parse(informacija[3]);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", narys[i].vardas, narys[i].pavarde, narys[i].eurai, narys[i].centai);

    islaidos = narys[i].eurai * 100 + narys[i].centai;
    narys[i].suma = islaidos / 100 * 0.25;
    islaidos = narys[i].suma;
    if(maxSuma < narys[i].suma)
    {
         maxSuma = narys[i].suma;
         maxIndex = i;
    }
    surinktiPinigai = surinktiPinigai + islaidos;
 }
 if(maxIndex>=0) Console.WriteLine(narys[maxIndex].suma);
```

Comment: I am getting error: CS1061  C# 'double' does not contain a definition for and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type 'double' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` to your directives

Comment: Yes i have added, first that you wrote works, but second one isn't

Comment: Max returns the maximum number not the item that had max number. you should use `MaxBy` from moreLinq

Comment: @GuruStron, your code is only returning the max `suma`, not the entire object that contains this value. So `maxNarys` is a `double`, not a `nariai`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary and you too)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to retrieve from the list the item with the max `suma` and then you can get it's other properties.

```
var item = narys.OrderByDescending(i => i.suma).FirstOrDefault();
var name = $"{item?.vardas} {item?.pavarde}";
```

Notice the use of the `?.` operator available since C# 6.0 that verifies `item` is not null. If by the time you perform this querying you know for sure that collection is not empty then simply:

```
var item = narys.OrderByDescending(i => i.suma).First();
var name = $"{item.vardas} {item.pavarde}";
```

You can also use MoreLinq's [`MaxBy`](https://morelinq.github.io/2.8/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_MaxBy__2_1.htm) which:

> Returns the maximal element of the given sequence, based on the given projection.